# 3 problems achieving a 10:00 minute countdown clock animation. (non-repeating seconds, changing 100 units to units of 60, minutes not following math)

Tags: add-on, physics, animation-nodes

I'm working on creating a COUNTDOWN ANIMATION of ten minutes 10:00 to 0:00 using the Animation Nodes Add On.

I can't find as yet a way to repeat the seconds portion so every 60 seconds so it recycles again starting over and repeating 9 more times. Is there s a loop node within the animation nodes?

I'm also unable to find a UNITS NODE offering an ability to change it's native 100, to 60. My workaround was to create two separate countdowns, one for minutes, and one for seconds next to each other. Of course one major problem with this is when the countdown begins, the minutes doesn't change from 10 to 9 immediately, instead changing 1/10th the time between 10:00 and 0:00.

Here's the current left to right setup of the nodes:

> Timer Info > Delay Time 10-0 > Animate Float > Float to Text > Text Object Output

> Timer Info > Delay Time  60-0> Animate Float > Float to Text > Text Object Output

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps, it is the online equivalent of shouting and is considered rude

Answer (score -1):

Use math operator integer modulus relative to a frame number.
pseudo programming language ... I think you can translate this to BAN

```
time = (10 * 60 )- ((frame - offset)) #bias can be used
hour = integer(time/60)
minute = time % 60 # modulus operation
```

please improve

Comment: I was very scared by your shouting.  